# Regex to identify escaped characters issue

Tags: c#, .net, regex, unicode, escaping

Let's suppose we have the following string:

```
@"Hello m\u00e9 name is Mat\u00bfQu"
```

I am using the regex:

```
private static readonly Regex ESCAPING_REGEX = new Regex("\\+[^\"][a-zA-Z0-9]*", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

However, this regex doesn't seem to return any matches:

```
MatchCollection matches = ESCAPING_REGEX.Matches(text);
// matches.Count == 0
```

I tried the regex on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fJ3sK4/1) and it does return the two matches that I was looking for.

How can I fix my regular expression to achieve expected behavior? (Any tips for improvement are gladly accepted.)

Comment: is your string in verbatim format?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I'm sorry for my ignorance. What is verbatim format?

Comment: The source of your problems! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Oh I see! My string is indeed in verbatim format. I will update my problem to reflect this. I tried removing the verbatim, but still no matches

Comment: Try to use a verbatim string for your pattern too.

Comment: You guys are truly the best! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex declaration is faulty because you require a literal `+` to be in the beginning of the match. Look what your regex looks like for a regex engine:

- `\+` - Matches a literal `+`
- `[^"]` - Matches any character other than `"`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - Matches 0 or more characters that are digits or Latin letters.

If you use a verbatim string literal to create your regex, e.g.

```
Regex.Matches(str, @"\\+[^""][a-zA-Z0-9]*");
```

you'd get 2 matches. `\\` in a verbatim string literal will match a literal `\`, and `+` will be treated as a quantifier.

Actually, you do not even need the `+` (since it will match `\\\\`) and `[^""]` (unless there can be some `"`s right after `\` and that is not what you want to match), you can use

```
@"\\[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
```

to match your substrings (`\\` matches a `\`, `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` will match 1 or more characters from the range).

[image]

Comment: @stribizhev "and + will be treated as a quantifier." - is this correct?

Comment: @greenfeet: Yes, [have a look at what `\\+[^"][a-zA-Z0-9]*` actually does](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5c%2b%5b%5e%22%5d%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d*&i=%5c%5c%5c%5c%5c%5c%5c).